# Is there a deployment deliverable(ear/war) for a web application running in Spring Tool Suite(STS)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a web application created using Spring boot and I am using Spring Tool Suite(STS) for developing it. If my understanding is correct, tomcat is internally embedded in STS and I can run/debug the application from STS with the help of Application.java.

Now my doubts are, when we run the application by running a java class as 'Spring Boot App'

1. What is the deployment deliverable?(ear/war)
2. Where exactly the deliverable getting deployed? I have searched
   everywhere in STS directories and could find it
3. If there is nothing like this, then how is it working?

Do this make sense or am I wrong with my understanding?

Comment: If you're using spring boot. it's more than likely building a JAR file which contains an embedded application server (probably Jetty)

Comment: More likely tomcat. This is the default in spring-boot, Jetty is also available as an option, but you'd have to do some stuff to the pom (or build.gradle) to remove tomcat and add Jetty as a dependency explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding about Spring Boot is wrong.

The embedded Tomcat is included on your application, when you use Spring Boot.

1. Spring Boot generates a .jar file. When the application is started, Spring knows how to bootstrap a Tomcat instance for you
2. If you are using the "Run" command on STS, there is no deliverable yet. The main method on `Application.java` has everything that is need for Spring run your application
3. Spring Boot is a project dedicated to create stand-alone Spring applications. As I said on first item, Spring Boot knows everything that is need to bootstrap a new Tomcat instance and run your application. You don't need an application server when working with Spring Boot, Spring provides by a embed Tomcat/Jetty or Undertow. The Tomcat is INSIDE your application with your code, not an external application server.

Comment: Spring-boot is also runable as a `war`. Then you dont have an embedded tomcat and need an external one.